# Hide image in responsiveness

Tags: html, wordpress, css

i am working on this sites responsive issue **http://technoalliance.ae/** here **http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnoalliance.ae%2F**

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
.span12 .row-dynamic-el:nth-of-type(2) .media_el .animation_right.start_animation:first-of-type{display:none;}}
```

but it is hiding two images the one with umbrella and one image with the map .
i need to hide the one with umbrella on responsivenes. but it is hiding two images in the given above css . is there any other way in css3 to solve the issue? please help
thanks

Comment: Please explain briefly, add some more code

Comment: i need to remove the image with umbrella which we can see in normal desktop but not in mobiles.when i added the above code it is hiding two images . one with the umbrella and one with the map

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress, i don't exactly, in css you will take two tags for those images

Comment: this is a wordpress developed site .. the classes are dynamic

Comment: you can add classes or IDs to an image in Wordpress. Change to text view to edit the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You must use a single `DIV` to display both images...

### HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 media media_el animate_onoffset start_animation" style="width:auto">
        <img src="http://technoalliance.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/indiamap.png" alt="" class="type_image media_animation animation_left alignment_left start_animation">  
        <img src="http://technoalliance.ae/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/uaemap.png" alt="" class="type_image media_animation animation_right alignment_left start_animation">
    </div>
</div>
```

And also, on Desktop view, apply:

```
.row-fluid .span6{
    width : auto;
}
```

No need to change anything in `CSS` & it will not hide any of MAP images.

Comment: but it is generating automaticaly through wordpress

Comment: like this : `<div style="width:auto">`